# Sending sound file with a SMS Intent?

Tags: android, android-intent

I have this code to fire SMS Intent :

```
String uri= "smsto:";
Intent smsIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO, Uri.parse(uri));
smsIntent.putExtra("sms_body", msgText);
smsIntent.putExtra("compose_mode", true);
startActivity(smsIntent);
```

I want to `attach a sound file (.amr file) to the message`. This file is in the `raw folder`.

Can I do this? and how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at [this](http://jtribe.blogspot.com/2008/12/sending-mms-with-android.html) for how to send an MMS and [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/AssetManager.html) to see how to get a stream to provide to the MMS intent.